# docker cp returns "no space left on device" if entire host filesystem is mounted

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is the definition of the docker container:

```
version: '2'

services:
    alpine-test:
       container_name: alpine-test
       image: alpine:latest
       command: tail -F /dev/null
       volumes:
           - /:/rootfs
```

If I try to copy a file from this container, eventually it returns "Error response from daemon: no space left on device" error:

```
# docker cp alpine-test:/etc/hostname /tmp/
# docker cp alpine-test:/etc/hostname /tmp/
# docker cp alpine-test:/etc/hostname /tmp/
Error response from daemon: no space left on device
#
```

I am failed to find any workaround or explanation of this.

I am using debian 9.8 and Docker Engine - Community 18.09.4

Thanks

Comment: Which OS are you running?

Comment: @wederer debian 9.8 Docker Engine - Community 18.09.4

Comment: It would be a reasonable starting point to demonstrate that the error message isn't *true*.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the error message is true. it does not copy the file.

Comment: I meant, is it true *that there's genuinely no space on the destination*? Of course, this requires figuring out a bunch of details -- what filesystem the destination *is*, f/e; if it's tmpfs, what percentage of RAM is permitted for its use; if it's subject to user quotas, where they are; etc.

Comment: Personally, I'd start by using `sysdig` to track down the actual failing syscall.